# when "bash -c" will cause child shell created?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

on my centos7.4 server,if run

```
bash -c "python -m SimpleHTTPServer"

pstree -sp 10784 (PID of python server)
```

will show

```
systemd(1)───sshd(922)───sshd(11595)───sshd(11597)───bash(11598)───python(11617)
```

and with

```
bash -c "python -V && python -m SimpleHTTPServer"
```

I got

```
systemd(1)───sshd(922)───sshd(11595)───sshd(11597)───bash(11598)───bash(11638)───python(11640)
```

so why a child shell created in the 2nd command?

Comment: Anyhow, compare to `bash -c 'python -V && exec python -m SimpleHTTPServer'`, or even (if you don't need your original/interactive shell back) `exec bash -c 'python -V && exec python -m SimpleHttpServer'` -- `exec` with non-redirection arguments tells the shell to replace itself with the program being started, such that the shell itself no longer remains in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second command uses a subshell to handle the `&&` operator - it needs to wait for SIGCHLD for the first command terminating and then decide whether or not the second command needs to be run.

In the first case - this seems to happen:
Bash starts up and sees that it needs to run a simple string. As an optimisation, it then [`exec`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve)s that command without forking first and the subshell is replaced by the python command.

For the second case, this optimisation does not work, and bash forks to run the `python -V` command and wait for the result. Upon receiving the SIGCHLD for that command exiting, it runs the second command (and does not apply the optimisation to prevent an additional [`fork`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork))

See around line 1370 [here](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c?id=7de27456f6494f5f9c11ea1c19024d0024f31112#n1370)

Answer (score 2):

`bash -c` always creates a new child shell. What happens in the first case is that the new shell is immediately replaced by the python process, via `execve()`:

```
bash (execve python - m SimpleHTTPServer)
```

as can be seen with `strace`:

```
$ strace -e clone,fork,vfork,execve -f bash -c "python2 -m SimpleHTTPServer"
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "python2 -m SimpleHTTPServer"], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
execve("/usr/bin/python2", ["python2", "-m", "SimpleHTTPServer"], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

In the second case, the new shell has to coordinate both processes: it has to launch the second command only if the first one succeeded. You'd have something like:

```
       +-- execve python -V
bash --+
       +-- execve python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

where `bash` first `fork()`s before `execve()`ing each command, as can be seen in:

```
$ strace -e clone,fork,vfork,execve -f bash -c "python2 -V && python2 -m SimpleHTTPServer"
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "python2 -V && python2 -m SimpleH"...], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7ff72d3049d0) = 8631
Process 8631 attached
[pid  8631] execve("/usr/bin/python2", ["python2", "-V"], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
Python 2.7.5
[pid  8631] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=8631, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7ff72d3049d0) = 8632
Process 8632 attached
[pid  8632] execve("/usr/bin/python2", ["python2", "-m", "SimpleHTTPServer"], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

Some shells may optimize the last command in a conditional, e.g. `zsh` may `execve()` `python -m simpleHTTPServer` directly, without forking first:

```
zsh (waits for subcommand, then execve python -m sim...) --- execve python -V
```

strace of that:

```
$ strace -e clone,fork,vfork,execve -f zsh -c "python2 -V && python2 -m SimpleHTTPServer"
execve("/bin/zsh", ["zsh", "-c", "python2 -V && python2 -m SimpleH"...], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f1c5c60a9d0) = 8670
Process 8670 attached
[pid  8670] execve("/usr/bin/python2", ["python2", "-V"], [/* 72 vars */]) = 0
Python 2.7.5
[pid  8670] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=8670, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
execve("/usr/bin/python2", ["python2", "-m", "SimpleHTTPServer"], [/* 72 vars */]) = 0
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of

```
bash -c "python -m SimpleHTTPServer"
```

bash do some optimisations as `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` is the only command to execute by the bash.

- `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` is the only thing to do, bash will not fork a child process for `bash -c`.
- for `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` (external command), bash will `fork` a new child process (`python`) to execute.
- child process will execute the external command `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` using `exec`.

While in case of

```
bash -c "python -V && python -m SimpleHTTPServer"
```

`python -V` cause bash to use a new shell calling `fork` and then `exec`.

- bash will `fork` a child process (`bash`) for `bash -c`.
- for the child process, `python -V` is an (external command) and it will `fork` a new child process (`python`) to execute it.
- child process will execute the external command `python -V` using `exec`.
- Once execution of `python -V` is complete parent shell will again `fork` a new child process (`python`) for the external command `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`.
- child process will execute the `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` using `exec`.

A simple example could be

```
$ pstree $$
bash---pstree
$ ( pstree $$ )
bash---pstree
$ ( pstree $$ ; echo)
bash---bash---pstree
```

---

Suggested reading: [Why (…) doesn't spawn a new child process when run in background?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/430050/186463)